# Accept doc and docx not working on Chrome?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

When I create simple input

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
```

Chrome allows all files, but in Firefox everything is fine, I guess Chrome was fine before, any idea?

```html
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
```

Comment: When I click Choose Files in Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10, it shows me *.doc and *.docx files to choose from.

Comment: I'm using Windows 11, maybe there is problem

Comment: This started to happen in MacOs as well.